# Derivative of an integral having variable limits

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have the following question before me:
It is given that
$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt=x+\int_{x}^{1} tf(t)dt$$

I have to find $f(1)$.
I took derivative of both sides of above equation with respect to $x$ and got the equation below:
$f(x)=1-xf(x)$

On rearranging, we get
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$
On putting $x=1$, we get
$f(1)=1/2$.

My first question is whether I have done it correctly so far?

When I tried checking whether $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$ satisfies the given equation, I found that LHS comes out to be $log(1+x)$ while the RHS comes out to be $1-log(2)+log(1+x)$.

Clearly two sides are not equal. They differ by a constant $1-log(2)$. Why is this the case? Does this mean that the $f(x)$ that I came up with is wrong?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4359710/495620), I explain here how you can show that $f(x)$ does not exist.

If you take the derivative of both sides of an equality, you are adding new solutions. This is because, if the derivative of two functions is equal, then the two functions are equal **up to an additive constant**. For example, for $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x+3$, we have
$$g(x)\ne h(x)$$
but
$$g'(x)=h'(x).$$

To solve a problem of the form $g(x)=h(x)$ by taking derivatives of both sides, you not only have to ensure that the derivatives are equal, but also that both functions are equal at one single value of $x$. That is, the equation
$$g(x)=h(x)$$
is equivalent to the **system**
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{array}{l}
g'(x)=h'(x) \\
g(x_0)=h(x_0).
\end{array}\right\} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where you can choose $x_0$ to be any single number in the domain of both $g$ and $h$.

In your problem
$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t=x+\int_{x}^{1} tf(t)\:\mathrm{d}t$$
we have $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t$ and $h(x)=x+\int_{x}^{1} tf(t)\:\mathrm{d}t$. Applying (1), the equation is then equivalent to the system:
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{array}{l}
f(x)=1-xf(x) \\
\int_0^1 f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t=1
\end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}
where I used $x_0=1$. As you derived correctly, the only solution of the first equation is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}.$$
This is incompatible with the second equation, as $\int_0^1 f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t=\log 2 \ne 1$. Therefore, the system is incompatible (has no solution) and the original equation also has no solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an error because there is no continuous function satisfying the given equation! You were right up to $f(t)=\frac 1 {1+t}$. But this function does not satisfy the given equation as seen by putting $x=0$: Even without evaluation we see that $\int_0^{1} \frac t {1+t} dt$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Does that mean that I have evaluated $f(1)$ correctly?

Comment: Well, you haven't done anything wrong but $f$ does not exist  and neither does $f(1)$. The question itself is wrong. @HARVEERRAWAT

Comment: Sir, to add further context to this question, this question was asked in this year UPSC CSE optional paper. Really when we put $x=0$, we get LHS as zero while RHS is a +ve quantity.

Comment: Mistakes do occur in such exams. Just ignotr the question and move ahead. @HARVEERRAWAT